# LWC: directive for comparison

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, string

Is it possible to compare a value with a string in LWC template tag?

```
<template if:true={v.value === 'String'}></template>
```

If not, how can I do this???

Answer (score 3):

LWC doesn't support expressions. You need to have a property somewhere you can read. This can be either a getter:

```
get isValueString() {
  return this.value === 'String';
}
```

Or as a property on your data:

```
this.data = this.data.map(datum => ({ ...datum, isValueString: datum.value === 'String' }));
```

Comment: in <template if:true={v.value === 'String'}></template>, the v.value comes from an iteration <template for:each={records} for:item="v">. how can I do in this case? what do I return in JS? `` return this.value === 'String';`` doesn't work.

Comment: @JeanMichell When `v` comes from an iteration, you need to inject a field into your data, as described at the end of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, in LWC you don't need `v.`. Just use the property name enclosed in two braces eg. `{propertyName}`.

You can't use expressions in the HTML markup of LWC. For this particular scenario, you can use the getter method in the JS controller.

```
get isSomething(){
    return this.value === 'String';
}
```

Use this in HTML like below.

```
<template if:true={isSomething}></template>
```

Comment: in ``<template if:true={v.value === 'String'}></template>``, the v.value comes from an iteration ``<template for:each={records} for:item="v">``. how can I do in this case?

what do I return in JS?
`` return this.value === 'String';`` doesn't work.

Comment: @JeanMichell check the second code block in the answer by Sfdcfox.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered by @sfdcfox, providing an example
HTML file :

```
<template>
    <template for:each={itemJsonArr} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.id}>
            {item.id}
            {item.name}
            <template if:true={item.showDesignation}>
                &nbsp;{item.designation}
            </template>
        </div>    
    </template>
</template>
```

Javascript file : A new "showDesignation:true/false" pair is used to distinguish each record based on some condition. Here for each record in the array we will have "showDesignation=false", and for "item.name === 'Dhoni'", showDesignation will be "true".

```
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    itemJsonArr = [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Sachin",
            "designation": "Manager"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Dhoni",
            "designation": "Senior Developer"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Virat",
            "designation": "Junior Developer"
        }
    ];

    itemJsonArrCopy = this.itemJsonArr.map(item => {
        if (item.name === 'Dhoni') {
            item.showDesignation = true;
        } else {
            item.showDesignation = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshot from LWC playground
[image]